# Contactform 7 Datepicker not working

Tags: wordpress, date, datepicker, contact-form-7

am using wordpress 4.5.9, contactform7 4.4.2 and contactform7 datepicker 2.6.0.

after updating contactform 7 and contactform7 datepicker, date field shows

[date* date-741 date-format:mm/dd/yy min-date:0 max-date:1 buttons placeholder "date"]

Please find the below link

[Date picker error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyRd6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass min and max date param like the following ,

```
[date* your-date min:today+0days max:today+10days step:1 class:required "Date"]
```

Also you need to use [datepicker extended plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-datepicker/) if above one not work.

Comment: Hi, I have used this plugin, but it doesn't work. and i need to set my min date as today (not a specefic day).

Comment: Try to pass 'today' in min and max. Also check jquery conflicts in console

Comment: Thankyou, [date* your-date min:today+0days  max:today+10days  step:1 class:required "Date"] This worked!